# Intersect multilinestring (A) with multilinestring (B) retaining linear sequencing in resultset?

Tags: postgis, intersection, tin

I have a PostGIS table **testtin2** which is a sort of pseudo TIN consisting of a single multilinestring geometry, which I am intersecting with another table **align**, also a multilinestring, to generate a set of coordinates along an alignment (or alignments) via the following query...

```
SELECT ST_X(q1.int_pnt), ST_Y(q1.int_pnt), ST_Z(q1.int_pnt)
FROM
(SELECT ST_Intersection(align.geom, testtin2.geom) as int_pnt 
FROM align INNER JOIN testtin2 ON ST_Intersects(align.geom, testtin2.geom)
WHERE ST_isvalid(align.geom)='t' AND ST_isvalid(testtin2.geom)='t') As q1;
```

Which works fine except for the fact that the resulting output is seemingly in a 'random' order. Is there a way this query might be modified or re-written such that the coordinates come out in the correct linear sequence along the alignment linestring(s) from the **align** table?

I need this to happen so that the drafting software I am passing the coordinates to will join the dots up in the correct order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...actually I suspect it may help if I break my alignment multilinestring into linestrings either beforehand or in the query somehow but I am not sure how to do this either.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Recreated the **align** table as linestrings (as opposed to a single multilinestring record) and then used the linear referencing function `ST_line_locate_point` to calculate the distance of each coordinate along the line it belonged to, before ordering the results by this value.

Thanks to anyone who looked.